# H2 Console in Spring Boot Integration Test

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2

I'm working with Spring Boot `1.3.1.RELEASE`. I enabled the H2 web console by setting `spring.h2.console.enabled=true` in the `application.properties` file. If I launch my Spring Boot application I can access the H2 Web console via `http://localhost:8080/h2-console/`.

However, I am not able to access the console when I perform an integration test in debug mode, where I have set a breakpoint. Unfortunately, this is not working (site is not available). The integration test is configured as follows:

```
@ActiveProfiles("local,unittest")
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyApplication.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@IntegrationTest
public class MyResourceTest {
```

What I have not considered?

Comment: Have you tried adding "test" to @ActiveProfiles ?

Comment: Yes, but this does not work as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To enable the H2 Web console,  you should agregate the value of your properties file related to this item as optional element of the annotation `@IntegrationTest`.

String[]value
Properties in form `key=value` that should be added to the Spring Environment before the test runs.

Example:

```
@IntegrationTest({"spring.h2.console.enabled=true"})
```

And keep in mind this recomendation :

> If your test also uses @WebAppConfiguration consider using the
>   @WebIntegrationTest instead of  @IntegrationTest

So, try to use `@WebIntegrationTest` instead of  `@IntegrationTest` and add the key `spring.h2.console.enabled = true`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/IntegrationTest.html

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/WebIntegrationTest.html

Maybe you could need add the key "server.port=8080" as another value for the annotation @WebIntegrationTest

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. Meanwhile I have tried it, but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Remove the annotation @IntegrationTest, your test finish with succes ?

Comment: No, it does not.  The following Exception is thrown: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'local.server.port' in string value "${local.server.port}"`

Comment: aahh , try to add "server.port=8080" as key of your annotation, put also this key in your properties file

Comment: it's loading...site never appears. But at least I no longer get an error :-)

Comment: try to change your port, ex 8081, run your test and go to http://localhost:8081/h2-console/.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102403/discussion-between-jesus-zavarce-and-rene-winkler).

Comment: Did you try creating a @Bean for the /console?

Comment: What more do you add to fix your problem ?

Comment: debugging seems to block the H2 console as well. I opened a new question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179110/spring-boot-is-blocking-h2-console-in-debug-mode